# How to group by and apply aggregate function to datetime for a specified period in panda in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with 2 columns.

The 1st column is a timestamp of every minute.
The 2nd column is a number.

All I want to do is to change the 1st column into timestamp of every 30 minutes, and the sum of the 30 numbers within that period from column 2.

[image: example dataframe]

Power is demonstrated for every minute and but I want to sum them up for every 30 minutes.

Comment: Please somebody help :(

Comment: you can set the timestamp as index, and use `series.resample('30T').sum()`

Comment: Please avoid posting images on SO and instead post a sample data frame code so others can help you better/faster. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll make sure I avoid that afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using pandas/Series.resample

[Series.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) can help you if set the timestamp as index ; then use `series.resample('30T').sum()`

### Manual version

You can use [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) over the serie you want to keep.

Then select only the index at every 30 positions (np.arange(0, len(df), 30).

Then iterate over the dataframe backward and substract at row n the sum found at row n-1 to keep only the value of the last 30 minutes. Iterating is not very efficient but since your dataset is 1M row, if you take 1 row every 30 rows, it should be fast (33,333 iterations).

```py
df['cumsum'] = df["Power_kw"].cumsum()
df_30_min = df.iloc[np.arange(0, len(df), 30)].copy()

for i in range(len(df_30_min), 1, -1):
    df_30_min.iloc[i-1, df_30_min.columns.get_loc('B')] -= df_30_min.iloc[i-2, df_30_min.columns.get_loc('B')]
```